# Promise resolves after Mocha times out

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai, es6-promise, web-worker

I have a worker I'm testing with Mocha, but even though I'm getting the proper response back from promise resolution, Mocha keeps failing the test due to timeout. Crucial fact is that it resolves after Mocha times out.

```
import chai, { expect } from 'chai';
// Needed otherwise Worker is undefined in the test environment
const Worker = require('webworker-threads').Worker;

describe('WebWorker', () => {
  it('should return correctly', () => {
    return new Promise(res => {
      const dummyWorker = new Worker('./public/js/worker.bundle.js');

      dummyWorker.onmessage = e => {
        console.log('test message'); // 'test message' prints to testing log
        res(e.data);
      };

      dummyWorker.postMessage(['foo', 'bar']);
    })
    .then(workerData => {
      console.log(workerData[0]); // 'foo' prints to testing log
      expect(workerData[0]).to.equal('foo');
    })  
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
  });
});
```

> Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.

I've tried <s>every</s> some permutations of using `done()`, using `before()` hooks, using chai-as-promised, using promises AND Mocha's done, using `this.timeout(5000)` to increase the timeout, and on and on, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: You should extend the timeout for mocha. Rewrite the `it` arrow function as regular function and add as first line `this.timeout(5000)`. This will make Mocha wait at least 5 seconds before complain.

Comment: @MarcoL Hey thanks for the suggestion. I actually tried that too, but had forgotten to include it in my list of things tried. I'll update the list now.

Comment: You are returning a Promise, so Mocha should properly wait for that to resolve.  This strongly suggests that `dummyWorker.onmessage(...)` is never being called.  Can you post what `./public/js/worker.bundle.js` is doing?

Comment: @PeterWagener Hi, I appreciate the help, but it can't be the worker because workerData is being returned from the promise resolving. If I were to add a test assertion that fails on purpose `expect(workerData[0]).to.equal('baz')`, it would print to screen that an AssertionError had occurred. The interesting part is that Mocha doesn't parse it's own AssertionError but simply returns it via `console.error(err)`. The error Mocha returns is still the timeout exceeded message. And yes, I've tried using the variants `.catch(err => done(err))` and `.catch(done)`

Comment: Can you create a plunkr/jsfiddle with the code?

Comment: You don't have an `after()` or `afterEach()` that may be causing it? FWIW, the `.catch()` will actually catch the assertion error and make the test succeed even if it should fail. Instead of using `.catch()`, use the second argument of `.then()`.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. The problem ended up being the npm package, webworker-threads. I made an error in reporting that the promise was resolving, but crucially omitted that it was resolving after Mocha timed out, which is an important distinction. Apologies. And @robertklep, thanks for the tip! I actually didn't know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have narrowed down the problem to the npm package webworker-threads. And what do you know. It's actually an [issue](https://github.com/audreyt/node-webworker-threads/issues/123) that hasn't been resolved yet.

It's only a problem when promises are involved. I thought I tried using `done()` inside of `dummyWorker.onmessage`, but I was sadly mistaken. Using `done()` with webworker-threads works just fine. The problem with using `done()` however is that any assertion error only ever returns the timeout message. With promises, the error message is much more specific.

Thus, I have switched over to using a different web worker package -- tiny-worker, and it works just fine now.

In the event you want to see the issue with webworker-threads, refer to the simple example below, which reproduces the error without needing an external file:

```
import { expect } from 'chai';
const Worker = require('webworker-threads').Worker;

describe('web worker', () => {
  it('should resolve', () => {
    const p = new Promise(resolve => {
      const dummyWorker = new Worker(function () {
        this.onmessage = e => {
          self.postMessage('foo');
        };
      });

      dummyWorker.onmessage = e => {
        resolve(e.data);
      };
      dummyWorker.postMessage('foo');
    });

    return p.then(data => {
      console.log(data));
      expect(data).to.equal('bar');
    }
  });
});
```